# Does Bind() or Eval() automatically HtmlEncode to protect against XSS?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, xss

Forgive me if this is a silly question.  I haven't been able to find the answer stated explicitly.

I rarely use Bind() or Eval() in my aspx pages, and instead use the following syntax: (Assume this is in an ItemTemplate in a Repeater control)

```
<asp:Label id="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.HtmlEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstName").ToString()) %>
```

I started doing this a long time ago and simply never questioned it, but now it occurs to me that this may be overkill.  And now I'm using a CMS that uses this syntax all over the place:

```
<asp:Label id="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>
```

So I'm wondering, basically, if I use Bind() or Eval() does the runtime automatically HtmlEncode the output?  Have I been doing unnecessary coding all along?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Bind() and Eval() do NOT do anything to prevent that type of thing and do not encode.  Neither do the `<%# %>` style code blocks.

However, if you are using ASP.NET 4 and later you can use `<%: %>` Blocks to handle this for response write type situations and `<%#: %>` for data bind situations.

Scott Guthrie has a great [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) about this.

Comment: That looks goocd, but it looks like it is meant for '<%=  %>' (Response.Write equivalent)  not '<%# %>' blocks as you'd see in a DataBinding context.  Is there an equivalent shorthand for true databound controls?

Comment: Never mind.  Found it here for 4.5: http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet/whats-new#_Toc318097391  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I would vote you up a few more times if I could. I've been finding unsafe usages of this this all over the place.